# MongoDB - rebuild document, keep last element of array

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Example document https://pastebin.com/x2kVUnP3

**Understanding The data**

Each of the fields array count is the same as the fetch_dates, so if we want to get a data set for *2019-06-07 05:34:29* it would return all the inner fields `$arrayElemAt = 1` for the latest result it would be -1 for the corresponding field.

[image: Data relation]

**Desired result**

The main idea is to rebuild all the documents and keep only the latest fetch_date and last value for each field. In that case, just keep the orange line of the image.

**Question**

Basically I got no idea where to start or how to start, and if that is possible to do. Each document can have different array sizes (fetch_dates) but the structure is the same. There is 225k documents to process, avg size 2.5kb. Any tips would be appreciated.

**My initial idea**

I thought to get all the fields and its last elements over a PHP script 
something like iterate over all documents first, then over all the fields and $project value `$arrayElemAt => [ $field3.field3_1, -1 ]` I assume that's a bad idea.

I am using PHP - Laravel, but I am able to convert the query to get it working there.

Comment: I think you can use $slice it will be better then using arrayElemAt https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/

Comment: When you say, "structure is the same," do you mean all of the documents have the same fields (but size of arrays may differ)? Or were you specifically only talking about the fetch_dates field?

Comment: I think your initial idea is good! Don't you?

Comment: @jcarter everything is the same just the size changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution purely from the MongoDB shell.

My solution relies on the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-framework) and using the [project operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). In your question you said,

> Each document can have different array sizes (fetch_dates) but the
>   structure is the same.

Based off of that, I see no reason to have to iterate over all of the documents in the database. Instead, you can pull just one document out of the database and use it to come up with a projection which should work with all of the documents in the database. Here is the code I came up with.

```
function buildProjection(doc, prepend) {
  var projection = {};

  Object.keys(doc)
    .forEach(key => {
      var val = doc[key];
      var path = prepend==null? key : prepend + '.' + key;

      if (key == '_id') {
        projection[key] = 1;

      } else if ( Array.isArray(val) ) {
        projection[key] = { '$slice' : [ '$'+path, -1 ] };

      } else if ( typeof val === 'object' && val !== null ) {
        projection[key] = buildProjection(val, path);

      } else {
        projection[key] = 1;
      }
    });

    return projection;
}

/*
 * Pull a document out of the database and build the projection based off of it.
 * You may want to specify a particular document in the findone
 * that you know to be structured correctly
*/
var sample = db.myCollection.findOne({});
var projection = buildProjection(sample, null);

db.myCollection.aggregate([
  // apply the build projection
  { $project: projection },
  // insert results into another collection
  { $out: 'rebuiltWithLatest' }
]);
```

I wasn't sure whether you wanted to save the results in another collection. I did so with this solution. It took a few seconds, but I had no trouble running this with 300k documents, which were much like your linked example.

If you only wish to view the documents, remove the $output operation from the aggregation pipeline. It will then return a cursor object that you can iterate to see additional results.

Comment: I just tested the script, and one thing is missing. As you noticed the fetch_date and any other Array.isArray(val) of a key rebuild as a string. So fetch_dates becomes a string, but it should be an array with key 0 and the extracted value. ( example : https://imgur.com/a/dMyJJmk ) its basically to keep the old array structure, not a raw latest string.

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft, My mistake. What needs to change in that case is the $arrayElemAt operator needs to be replaced with the $slice operator. I have updated my answer.